# Stored Procedure sends two emails

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, stored-procedures

---

**EDIT**
[My previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590225/why-is-this-procedure-generating-two-emails) on this subject involved specific transactions within the procedure which are no longer used and the error now only seems to occur in a very specific set of circumstances when I use an invalid user name to our companies email address `badname@ourcompany.co.uk`

---

The agent runs a stored procedure every ten minutes to send out emails. If it finds a new record then it sends a mail.

Noticed some strange behavior - if the `TO` field is correct but the `BCC` is an invalid email address but uses our valid company domain name (e.g. `rubbishPart@ourcompany.co.uk`) then the stored procedure sends out two emails to the `TO`. The domain name needs to be our company's domain name to get this behavior ...if I change the domain to `gmail.com` then only one mail goes out.

- Why is this happening?
- How do I change this behavior?
- Is the `Catch` in this procedure redundant?

Here is the procedure:

```
BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @Exit TINYINT = 0
    WHILE @Exit = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @MailIdFound INT =
            (
            SELECT  CASE 
                WHEN MIN(EmailId) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE MIN(EmailId)
                END
            FROM    WH.dbo.EmailQueue
            WHERE   DateEmailKey IS NULL

            )

        IF @MailIdFound = 0 
            BEGIN SET @Exit = 1 END --exit here as  
        ELSE

            BEGIN --send the mail here

                DECLARE @DateEmailKey INT
                DECLARE @EmailBCC  NVARCHAR(1000)
                DECLARE @EmailTO  NVARCHAR(1000)
                DECLARE @EmailCC NVARCHAR(1000)
                DECLARE @EmailBody NVARCHAR(MAX)
                DECLARE @EmailImportance VARCHAR(6)
                DECLARE @EmailSubject NVARCHAR(1000);

                WITH myMostUrgentMail_cte
                    AS
                    (
                    SELECT  TOP 1
                            DateEmailKey,
                            EmailBCC,
                            EmailTO,
                            EmailCC,
                            EmailBody,
                            EmailImportance,
                            EmailSubject
                    FROM    WH.dbo.EmailQueue
                    WHERE   EmailId = @MailIdFound
                    )
                SELECT  @DateEmailKey = DateEmailKey,
                        @EmailTO = EmailTO,     
                        @EmailCC = EmailCC,                     
                        @EmailBCC = EmailBCC,
                        @EmailBody = EmailBody,
                        @EmailSubject   = EmailSubject
                FROM    myMostUrgentMail_cte;

                SET @EmailBody = @EmailBody + '<html>&#13;&#13;<span style=''font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:black''><p><b>blah blah</b></p></span></html>'
                EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
                    @recipients = @EmailTO,  
                    @copy_recipients = @EmailCC,
                    @blind_copy_recipients = @EmailBCC,
                    @subject = @EmailSubject,
                    @Importance = @EmailImportance,
                    @body_format = 'html',
                    @body = @EmailBody  

                UPDATE  x
                SET x.DateEmailKey = (CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),(112))),
                    x.DateEmailTime = (CONVERT([time](7),left(CONVERT([char](12),GETDATE(),(114)),(8)),(0)))
                FROM WH.dbo.EmailQueue x
                WHERE x.EmailId = @MailIdFound

            END

    END

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

        -- handle error here
        EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
                @recipients = 'ME@ME.com;'
            , @subject = 'ERROR OCCURED DURING EMAIL CREATION'
            , @body_format = 'html'
            , @body = 'ERROR OCCURED'

        UPDATE x
        SET x.ErrorOccured = 1
        FROM WH.dbo.EmailQueue x
        WHERE x.EmailId = @MailIdFound

END CATCH;
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to [your other question from 6 months ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13590225/397952)

Comment: @JNK...whoops...although its still erroring. Even if I add in the "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'" it still sends two mails. Now I have noticed that the problem only occurs when it is an invalid mail using our own company domain.

Comment: Could it be related to the email format?  Like using a two-part domain (.co.uk) instead of one (.com)?

Comment: ah sorry - I've used the wrong terminology...if I use our company's stub with an invalid username - `rubbishname@correctComp.co.uk` then it sends two mails - one 60seconds after the other. If I replace with 'rubbishname@googlemail.co.uk` then it only sends one mail

Comment: In that case it could be your mail server...

Comment: ok - any ideas how I confirm this? any ideas how I force the proc to only execute `sp_send_dbmail` once?

Comment: Sorry, not an admin.  But it sounds like it could be retrying if there's an error sending the email.

Comment: @JNK ok - thanks for thinking about this. Fingers crossed it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Have you tried sending the same e-mail yourself?  If there's an issue with your mail server issue, it should replicate regardless of who generates the e-mail.  Perhaps it's set up to forward e-mails sent to unrecognized e-mail addresses to your recipient.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades thanks - I just tested with my valid address in TO and `rubbishname@correctComp.co.uk` in the CC field. Tow return mails then hit my inbox - the email first and then a Microsoft Exchange mail titled "Undeliverable: blah blah"